# Initializing state in constructor versus state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the difference between those two ways to set initial state in ES6 besides the access to the props?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        highlighted: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3', 
    }
}
```

vs:

```
 state = {
        highlighted: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3',
    }
```

Comment: Not sure how it is compiling for you. The moment I write `state = {
        highlighted: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3',
    }` inside a class (not within a constructor method) in my jsx file I start getting compilation error - `Unexpected token` pointing to the `=` sign after state. Am I missing something at my end? The first code snippet is perfectly alright.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former is just syntax suger for the latter, so access to constructor arguments really is the only difference.

[This is how it gets transpiled by Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=stage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=class%20Example%20%7B%0A%20state%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20highlighted%3A%205%2C%0A%20backgroundColor%3A%20%27%23f3f3f3%27%2C%0A%20%7D%0A%7D&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false) using only `babel-preset-stage-2` preset to handle the proposed class properties syntax:

```
class Example {
  state = {
    highlighted: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3',
  }
}
```

Output:

```
class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      highlighted: 5,
      backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3'
    };
  }
}
```

---

This is also why declaring a function using a class property arrow function binds it to the instance.

[It gets moved into the constructor](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=stage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=class%20Example%20%7B%0A%20boundFunction%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%2F%2F%20...%0A%20%7D%0A%7D&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false), where the `this` value the arrow function preserves is the new instance.

```
class Example {
  boundFunction = () => {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Output:

```
class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.boundFunction = () => {
      // ...
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: In the second syntax that OP has used, can he not use `this.props` while setting any of `highlighted` or `backgroundColor` properties in the object?